# How to execute function after binding in angular1.5 using module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding

I'd like to execute initialize function using binding property like below when a page loaded after binding.

```
function MyController(){
  var my = this;
  my.init = function(){
    if(my.bindproperty == null) 
      //I'd like to set value to my.bindproperty in init function if my.bindproperty is null.

  }
}
```

`bindproperty` is binded in component.

```
var app = angular.module('App');
app.component('myDirective', {
  bindings: {
    bindproperty: '='
  },
  controller: MyController,
  templateUrl: 'path/to/view.html'
}
```

I tried to use `ng-init()`, but it couldn't read `my.bindproperty` at the moment.

HTML are like below.

```
<!--in parent directive-->
<div>
  <my-directive bindproperty="$ctrl.parentProperty"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also provide the HTML snippet where you are using this function?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added html snippet.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way:

```
function MyController() {
  var my = this;

  if(my.bindproperty == null) {
    // do something;
  }
}
```

A little cleaner:

```
function MyController() {
  var my = this;

  (function init() {
    if(my.bindproperty == null) {
      // do something;
    }
  })();
}
```

Also, your `bindproperty` may be `undefined` or an empty string rather than `null`.

You may want to do a more generic check (e.g. `if (!my.bindproperty)`) or something more specific (e.g. `my.bindproperty !== 'some valid bind property'`).

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't tell what I want to do well. I want to set value to `my.bindproperty` if `my.bindproperty` is `null`. Now It is `undefined` as you said.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. Is the check for null not working?